# Hide or encript formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, syntax, hide

I am working with Google Sheets for a department and would like to know if there is a way for me to be the only one to see the formulas I have created in the cells.

I know I can hide them from the menu, but it can be turned back on. And I also know that anyone can download the file and see any formula.

So is there any way for anyone to see the formulas even if they download the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible and anyways wouldn't be good practice.

Comment: @nullability What I want is that my effort and my work cannot be stolen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is possible to achieve only if you use IMPORTRANGE. create the spreadsheet and fill it with formulae. then create another spreadsheet and import the whole sheet into it. this way you are the only one who has all the formulae so no one can steal your work.